# SQLAlchemy: Issue with One-to-One relationship object creation

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy, relationship, one-to-one

I am new to SQLAlchemy and I was trying to run samples given in its documentation [Basic Relationship Patterns - One to One Relationship](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/basic_relationships.html#one-to-one). However as I try to instantiate the Parent class, I get into trouble.

Basically, what I have is:

```
class Parent(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'parent'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    child = relationship("Child", uselist=False, back_populates="parent")

class Child(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'child'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    parent_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('parent.id'))
    parent = relationship("Child", back_populates="child")

p1 = Parent()
```

The tables are made and are listed by .tables at sqlite> prompt, but at the line p1 = Parent() I receive this:

> sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: reverse_property 'parent' on relationship Parent.child references relationship Child.parent, which does not reference mapper Mapper|Parent|parent

This doesn't happen for one-to-many relationship and for this piece of code I get **[ ]** and **None** printed out as I expect:

```
class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'user'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)

    addresses = relationship("Address", back_populates="user")

class Address(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'address'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    email = Column(String)
    user_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('user.id'))

    user = relationship("User", back_populates="addresses")


u1 = User()
a1 = Address()

print(u1.addresses)
print(a1.user_id)
```

So, I don't quite understand what the SQLAlchemy error message is trying to tell me.

Can anyone help please?

Comment: **Update:** I tried instantiating Child instead of Parent and I got the exact same error, i.e., __sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: reverse_property 'parent' on relationship Parent.child references relationship Child.parent,
which does not reference mapper Mapper|Parent|parent__  
Does this mean there's something missing/superfluous or even wrong with the mapping code in the reference document?

Answer (score 3):

Ok, there is an obvious mistake in the document code. I'm posting this just in case anyone else runs to the same issue.

Basically, the relationship line in **Child** class, must be to the **Parent** class, and **not** to the **Child** class itself, as is in the documentation.

This code is corrected and works as expected (marked the modified part):

```
class Parent(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'parent'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    child = relationship("Child", uselist=False, back_populates="parent")

class Child(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'child'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    parent_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('parent.id'))
    parent = relationship("Parent", back_populates="child")
                           ^^^^^^
p1 = Parent()
c1 = Child()

print(p1.id)
print(c1.parent_id)
```

Which prints out **None** and **None** as expected.

And that's all!